# Progress bar while URL loading in WebView

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

I have the below code to show a progress bar loading as the URL loads in WebView.  However the line of code:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

has an error:

```
The constructor MyWebViewClient() is undefined
```

What else is needed for this to work?

WebViewActivity:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

private WebView webView;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);

ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(WebViewActivity.this);

webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(pb));
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
    switch(keyCode)
    {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    }

}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

MyWebViewActivity:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

private ProgressBar progressBar;

 public MyWebViewClient(ProgressBar pb) {
   this.progressBar=pb;
   pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
}

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

}
```

Crash Log:

```
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{app.myapp/app.myapp.WebViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at app.myapp.MyWebViewClient.<init>(MyWebViewClient.java:18)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at app.myapp.WebViewActivity.onCreate(WebViewActivity.java:23)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
10-17 20:18:35.774: E/AndroidRuntime(10492):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

`The constructor MyWebViewClient() is undefined` This error comes when used constructor is not available in Class. As I can see you have only one Constructor `public MyWebViewClient(ProgressBar progressBar)`. in `MyWebViewClient` Class

So you can not create instance of `MyWebViewClient` class without passing `ProgressBar` instance to the constructor.

Comment: so if I add private ProgressBar progressBar; and webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(progressBar)); I get no errors but the application crashes

Comment: You have not instantiated progressBar. And in constructor of your WebViewClient you are making and progressBar visible which is not yet instantiated. Instantiate progressBar in your Activity and then pass the instance to your WebViewClient.

Comment: so if I add ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(); to my Activity this should work?

Comment: Just doing `ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();` will not help. Reffer [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/progressdialog/android-progressdialog-example/)link. It will help you learn ProgressBar.

Answer (score 1):

```
public MyWebViewClient(ProgressBar progressBar) {
    this.progressBar=progressBar;
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The constructor has a ProgressBar as an argument as shown above.You have to pass a progress bar as parameter.

Comment: I have updated the code in the question, now it reads webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(pb)); and has no errors, the app works fine but doesnt show the progress bar as the URL loads

Answer (score 0):

```
public class google extends Activity {
    WebView video_player_view;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.google);
        video_player_view=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
         video_player_view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
           video_player_view.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
           video_player_view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
           video_player_view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
              video_player_view.loadUrl("YOUR URL");
              pd= new ProgressDialog(this);
              pd.setTitle("Webpage loading");
              pd.setCancelable(false);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            switch(keyCode)
            {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if(video_player_view.canGoBack()){
                    video_player_view.goBack();
                }else{
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

     private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
          @Override
          public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              view.loadUrl(url); 
              view.addJavascriptInterface(new Object()
              {
                  @JavascriptInterface
                public void performClick() throws Exception
                {
                    Log.d("LOGIN::", "Clicked");
                     Toast.makeText(google.this, "Login clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
              }, "login");
             return true;
          }

          @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              System.out.println("started");
              pd.show();
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);



        }



          @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              pd.dismiss();
              System.out.println("ends");
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);



        }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented this and it works great for me:

```
private WebView socialWebView;
private ProgressDialog loadPageDialog;


    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.web_view_social);

    socialWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.socialWebView);
    socialWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}


private void initData() {
    loadPageDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    loadPageDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
    loadPageDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    loadPageDialog.setCancelable(true);
    loadPageDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    if(loadPageDialog != null && !loadPageDialog.isShowing()) {
        loadPageDialog.show();
    }

    socialWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap facIcon) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            if(loadPageDialog != null && loadPageDialog.isShowing()) {
                loadPageDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

After the page load the dialog will dismiss, hope this is what you are looking for